# Transform list of one items type to list of another items type

Tags: android, kotlin

Android Studio 3.6

Snippet:

```
private fun createHistoryList(participantsEffectResourceList: List<ParticipantsEffectResource>) {
        val historyList = mutableListOf<MyHistoryItem>()
        participantsEffectResourceList.forEach({
            val date = it.operation.appliedAt
            val details = it.operation.details
            val myHistoryItem = MyHistoryItem(date, details)
            historyList.add(myHistoryItem)
        })
    }
```

As you can see I extract property from one item type (`ParticipantsEffectResource`) and transform it to another list of items (`MyHistoryItem`).

Nice. It's work fine.

But can any another simpler method? E.g. by `participantsEffectResourceList.map {}` or smt else?

Comment: List already provides `.map{}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List` already provides `.map()` you can use:

```
fun createHistoryList(participantsEffectResourceList: List < ParticipantsEffectResource > ) {
    val historyList = participantsEffectResourceList.map {
         MyHistoryItem(it.operation.appliedAt, it.operation.details)
     }
}
```